# Testing Devise Using capybara rspec and factory girl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, rspec, devise

i'm new at rails and i'm testing my devise gem User with capybara rspec and factory girl.

Here's spec code:

```
require 'rails_helper'
RSpec.describe User, type: :request do
  it "displays the user's email after successful login" do
    user = FactoryGirl.create(:user, email: 'test@test.com', password: 'password')
    visit root_url
    fill_in 'Email', with: 'test@test.com'
    fill_in 'Password', with: 'password'
    click_button 'Log in'
    expect page.has_content?('jdoe')
  end
end
```

The problem is in

> expect page.has_content?('jdoe')
>   No matter what i put instead 'jdoe' test works perfectly without any errors.

Here's factory:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    email 'test@test.com'
    password 'password'
    password_confirmation 'password'
  end
end
```

Maybe I missed something or going with a wrong way. How should I test here?

Comment: Can you try `expect(page).to have_content 'test@test.com'`

Comment: 1 example, 0 failures as with an 'jdoe'

Comment: So the test with `expect(page).to have_content 'jdoe'` is also green, I understood correctly?

Comment: @OleksandrAvoyants yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
# spec/features/sessions_spec.rb
require 'rails_helper'
RSpec.feature "Sessions" do
  scenario "displays the user's email after successful login" do
    user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
    visit root_url
    fill_in 'Email', with: user.email
    fill_in 'Password', with: user.password
    click_button 'Log in'
    expect(page).to have_content("Signed in successfully")
    # will give a false postitive if form is rerended?
    expect(page).to have_content(user.email) 
  end
end
```

A few things here:

1. Use a [feature](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/feature-specs/feature-spec) and not a request spec for end to end testing.
2. Don't hardcode object attributes. The whole point of factories is that the factory takes care of generating unique data so that the tests don't give false positives due to residual state.
3. Use `expect(page).to` instead of `expect page.should`. `expect(page).to` sets a subject and uses a RSpec matcher which will show you the text of the page in an error message if it does not match.

Comment: There is typo, should be `expect(page).to have_content(user.email)` (without question mark)

Comment: 1) Sessions displays the user's email after successful login
     Failure/Error: expect(page).to have_content?(user.email)
       expected #<Capybara::Session:0x007fa2fcfe91f0> to respond to `has_content??` error after test run

Comment: @OleksandrAvoyants

Comment: Okey, finally I did it. Your answer was really helpful, thanks :)